# Does $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\sin n\right|^\frac1n$ where $n\in\mathbb Z^+$ exist?

Tags: calculus, analysis, limits

> Does $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\sin n\right|^\frac1n$ where $n\in\mathbb Z^+$ exist?

How can I determine this using freshman calculus?

Comment: this reslut is 1

Answer (score 2):

solution: let $m>1$ and $|n-m\pi|<\dfrac{\pi}{2},m<n$,use this
$$|n-m\pi|>\dfrac{1}{m^{41}}$$
then
$$1>|\sin{n}|=|\sin{(n-m\pi)}|>\dfrac{2}{\pi}|n-m\pi|>\dfrac{2}{\pi n^{41}}$$

where use
$$\sin{x}>\dfrac{2}{\pi}x,0<x<\dfrac{\pi}{2}$$

and use 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}n^{\frac{1}{n}}=1,\lim_{n\to\infty}a^{\frac{1}{n}}=1(a>0)$$
then we have
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}|\sin{n}|^{\frac{1}{n}}=1$$

Comment: Where did the 41 come from?

Comment: can see" K.Mathler,On the approximation of $\pi$,Indag,Math.,15(1953),30-42

Comment: Better values than 41 is also available, but does not affect proof of this problem anyway.

Comment: It looks like there's a typo in the last expression in the second line above: "$n^{41}$" should be "$m^{41}$".